# Does the Android Manifest affect build in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

This is my first post on stack overflow so please be easy going here. It's also been a couple years since I've made an app so my conceptual understanding is not what it used to be.

My goal at the moment is to set up RTSP service for my mobile app.

I am having trouble getting the plugin I am using to connect to anything on the internet so one of my first debugging steps is to make sure the `AndroidManifest.xml` file is okay.

Below, is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ad_hoc.ad_hoc">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <application
        android:label="ad_hoc"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Will the flutter build be effected if I have a few errors in my manifest file? I'm able to run the app, but I'm not sure if my internet permissions are working therefore I am unsure.

Here are the following errors I am getting in my manifest file:

> "Unresolved class MainActivity" and "Attribute android:launchMode is
> not allowed here"

The "is not allowed here" errors are occurring for multiple attributes. Should I resolve these or leave be? I've built new projects to see if this problem persists and it does. Not sure how to solve this.

For the unresolved class, I'm not sure how to get the manifest to recognize the main activity I use in my `main.dart.xml` file. The name of the primary `Activity` is not `MainActivity`.

Any pointers/help would be much appreciated.

Are there any simple tests that I can do to make sure that my app is able to connect to the internet?

So to summarize my question, will the internet permissions be granted although I have these problems in the manifest file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when building or running on an android device the manifest will obviously have an effect on running the app. But - if your `AndroidManifest.xml` would really contain those errors the app would not launch in the first place.

My guess would be you either look at the wrong `AndroidManifest.xml` or your Android Studio has some problems. First make sure you are actually in the android module, and not in the root flutter project. ie. not in `myproject/` but in `myproject/android` (in Android Studio you can use "Tools -> Flutter -> Open For Editing in Android Studio").

If you are really in the correct module, try to run from inside Android Studio which is opened from your Android app, not from the root folder. This might give you more error messages.

Also: by default the `debug` variants of the android manifest from the default flutter project template will include the internet permission. So if you don't change anything it's possible that the debug builds work, but the release builds are missing the internet permission.

Comment: I think it's a problem with intelli J or something. I don't see the errors when I open the android folder in android studio. I ended up being able to resolve my connection problem by using a different plugin. So at least I think the manifest isn't really much of a problem for now. However I will try to be careful for release build.

Comment: @cap You should always open the `android` submodule in it's own IDE instance. If you *really* want to edit the android project from within the flutter project you can enable the experimental feature "Enable code completion, navigation, etc. for Java / Kotlin" https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/4819#issuecomment-690774332

Comment: I'm not sure if I can directly edit the source code however. I looked at the source code and there was a flutter wrapper with empty code within the class. Not sure how Android Studio is able to still build the files although the language is written in Dart. Maybe Flutter compiles it into Java code but unsure. But for modifying build/config files this sounds like a great debug idea.